# What does "the Latex template does not allow for keywords" mean?

Tags: templates, ieeetran

I'm new to paper writing in LaTex and looking at the paper submission guideline of one IEEE conference, what does "the Latex template does not allow for keywords" mean in the description?
[image: Paper submission guideline]

I don't know if keyword refers to index terms or something related to LaTex template(such as footnote etc.).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It would be helpful to show a link to the source of the text you are quoting. But if you look at the Word templates that IEEE supply, they show a line with keywords (index terms) right after the abstract.  The term `keyword` has no meaning in TeX.

Comment: But the line is odd, since the IEEE classes do supply an `IEEEkeywords` environment for these. So I would ask the conference specifically what they mean by the line.

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.ijcnn.org/paper-submission-2021

Comment: Thanks for your comment:)

Comment: @AlanMunn: can you give some information about the program chair's reply?

Comment: @user3352632 I have nothing to do with the original question other than the comments I made.

Comment: @Hoodythree: can you give some information about the program chair's reply what to do with the keywords?

Comment: @AlanMunn sorry, I mentioned the wrong person!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common piece of boilerplate text on a number of IEEE conferences. It's a bit odd because as Alan Munn noted in his comment, the IEEE classes do include an `IEEEkeywords` environment for providing keywords. But in this instance, they're telling you not to use that environment. Presumably production might be using a different version of the IEEE classes or otherwise processing things in a way that invalidates that environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here's the link: ijcnn.org/paper-submission-2021, you can check the detailed information.

Comment: OK, this means no keywords should be added to the paper in this case.